# How to solve 'this.props.items is undefined' in React.js on Firefox?

Tags: json, reactjs, firefox, axios, mozilla

I have made a component for SelectBox. When i send data in JSON format with axios, it is not working correctly in the new version of Mozilla Firefox. Testing on Chrome, IE and previous version of Firefox it works correctly, but in the new version of Firefox it shows the error "this.props.items is undefined". Could anyone guide me on how to solve this problem?

```
"@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"core-js": "^3.1.4",
"es6-promise-promise": "^1.0.0",
"history": "^4.9.0",
"raf": "^3.4.1",
"react": "^16.8.5",
"react-countdown-clock": "^2.6.0",
"react-dom": "^16.8.5",
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.8"
```

---component selectBox---

```
class SelectBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.props.onChange} className={this.props.className}>
          {this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
            return (
              <option value={item.value} key={i} id={i}>
                {item.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---page i use this Component---

```
class Real extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comboListMonth: [],
      month: "a"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/month.json").then(response => {
      let ArrItem = [];
      ArrItem.push({ value: "-1", name: "aa" });
      response = response.data;
      for (let i in response) {
        let item = { value: response[i].value, name: response[i].name };
        ArrItem.push(item);
      }
      this.setState({ comboListMonth: ArrItem });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <SelectBox
        items={this.state.comboListMonth}
        valueSelect={this.state.month}
        id={"combo-2"}
        onChange={this.handleChangeActive()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be related to the browser. Since you are getting your data in an async way in the first render it is not defined in the `SelectBox` component. So, you should consider conditional rendering.

Comment: Also, I can't see the `handleChangeActive` function in your component but if you use it as you do in your code,  it does not work as you intended. You are invoking it immediately. So, do not invoke it, just use the reference. `onChange={this.handleChangeActive}`

Comment: As in the second look, you are initializing your `comboListMonth` as `[]`, so you don't need a conditional rendering there I guess. Something is probably messing up your state in the fetch part. Can wee see your `month.json`?

Comment: as devsekran said, can we see your month.json?

Comment: yes i can see @KannanG

Comment: i can see month.json and in my code  i write handleChangeActive but in question i think is not neccessary for write it

Comment: SetState is an asynchronous action. Therefore there is no guarantee that the state will be set before you render the component. Hence, the conditional rendering.

Comment: edit code: remove setState in code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add condition before your options renders

if this.props.items has data then only render options in select.

see below code,

```
<select onChange={this.props.onChange} className={this.props.className}>
      {this.props.items && this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
        return (
          <option value={item.value} key={i} id={i}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestion,

1. Before iterating an array please make sure on adding error handling. In your case check this.props.item present or not before proceeding iteration
2. I am seeing the below setState({}) on your componentDidMount() which is not needed

`axios.get("/month.json").then(response => {
this.setState({}); // not needed? its updating the state without reason.
        .......
        .......
        .......
        this.setState({
           comboListMonth: ArrItem /*make sure you received data in expected format in your case its an array of object before setting*/
        });
    });`